# Playing encrypted MP4

Tags: encryption, mp4, mpeg-dash

I'm making a **(local - Multi-Platform) video protection app** but I don't know what is the right solution to first "encrypt->save on HDD" and then **"load from HDD->decrypt->play"** encrypted video.

I read about MPEG-DASH and some DRMs and found this Bento4 command:

```
mp4dash --encryption-key=000102030405060708090a0b0c0d0e0f:00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff --encryption-args="--property 1:ClearLeadFragments:10 --property 2:ClearLeadFragments:10" movie.mp4
```

but I'm not sure that MPEG-DASH can be a part of solution or not.

How can I solve this?

Comment: It seems you are missing the basics. Otherwise i can't understand why you would choose to use a format which was optimized for internet-streaming (you seem to want to work in a local-environment). An ffmpeg-based solution should be easy to do, which can play from aes-encrypted streams. Google a bit. A warning: the task of yours might get complicated when you assume, that an attacker has some access to your memory. I'm not sure, how these kind of attacks are countered in practice, but even some good password-managers like keepass need a lot of extra-code to be more safe!

Comment: @sascha I have enough knowledge about reverse engineering and I know it's possible to get memory content by dumping a process. but if you decrypt and load your content in multi frames (not to put your complete clear text file in memory) it's so harder to dump and merge it. so, which file format (instead mpeg) or solution can you offer?

Comment: You can use any format (should probably support streaming) and just use ffmpeg do do the encryption. What's so hard about googling it yourself? 1 min max to obtain first steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many searches on google I found the answer of [@erti-chris-eelmaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936622/erti-chris-eelmaa) here:

[Playing encrypted video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316729/playing-encrypted-video)

> I wrote my own Videoplayer using openGL+FFMPEG that could play mp4 and
>   decrypt each frame in the GPU using shaders. I also experimented with
>   another possible solutions, such as streaming from a webserver using
>   VLC. (VLC offers some kind of encryption/decryption when dealing with
>   streams), and yada yada yada.
>
> Also one solution was to use 4 mediaelements(WPF) and the actual video
>   was virtually split into 4 areas and each area was rotated so the
>   video was not viewable. Once you loaded the video into 4
>   mediaelements, you could map out which part you wanted to show and
>   also rotate it back. But in all honesty, MediaElement is bad.
>
> However I ended up exactly with what RomanR said. I built DirectShow
>   graph using mp4splitter, ffdshow, videorenderer and I modified
>   mp4splitter sourcefilter. The reading happens in
>   BaseSplitter/AsyncReader.cpp (just modify SyncRead function) that
>   mp4splitter uses.
>
> If you would like to implement it yourself, just use MPC-HC project
>   and modify the filters as you like. It took me some time to get around
>   the DirectShow concept, but once you understand it, it becomes great
>   weapon.

Answer (score 0):

HLS + S3 + CloudFront + MediaConvert + VideoJS.